# Highcharts - create theme that specifies set of default series' marker properties

Tags: highcharts

I can easily create a theme that defines the set of colors to be used for each series:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors: ['red', 'green', 'blue']
})
```

but how do I define a set of marker properties, such as `symbol` and `dashStyle`, to use for each series?

I can't find any description of this on Highcharts website, and the solution provided by their ChatGPT solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plotOptions` in `Highcharts.setOptions()` to set specific marker symbol and dash style.

```js
Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors: ['red', 'green', 'blue'],
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dashStyle: 'Dash',
            marker: {
                symbol: 'square',
            }
        }
    }
})
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6L1x43k2/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.marker

Another option if you want to set different orders of symbols you can use the symbol's property:

```js
Highcharts.setOptions({
  symbols:["square", "triangle-down", "circle"]
});
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5y38jenx/

Comment: Yes, thanks, this works for some properties. But there are a number of additional properties that I can't seem to set on a per series basis using `setOptions`, such as `dashStyle`, `lineWidth`, `radius`, and `fillColor`. Any ideas on how to handle those?